# Find number of cores on a linux machine using .Net Core failed with error (Unterminated quoted String)

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, .net-core, sh

I wrote the following code in .Net Core to retrieve number of cores of machine running a Ubuntu OS.

```
var proc = new Process
{
   StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
   {
      FileName = "/bin/sh",
      Arguments = "-c 'grep \"$0\" /proc/cpuinfo | uniq | sed -e \"$1\"' \"cpu cores\" 's/[^0-9]*//g'",
      UseShellExecute = false,
      RedirectStandardOutput = true,
      CreateNoWindow = true
   }
};

proc.Start();
string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

The command gives expected result if I execute it on putty but fails with error when I try to run it inside my .Net Core code.

Error: $0: 1: $0: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Any sh and .Net-Core expert who can explain what is wrong with my code?

Comment: your command returns nothing for me when run from command line.. so and my cpuinfo has it in.

Comment: I does return '2' as a answer on my machine if executed directly on shell

Comment: Personally Id have stuck with a simpler : grep "cpu cores" /proc/cpuinfo | awk -F: '{s+=$2} END {print s}'

Comment: running sh -c $'grep \"$0\" /proc/cpuinfo | uniq | sed -e \"$1\"' \"cpu cores\" 's/[^0-9]*//g'  returned absolutely nothing

Comment: Try this /bin/sh -c 'grep "$0" /proc/cpuinfo | uniq | sed -e "$1"' "cpu cores" 's/[^0-9]*//g'

Comment: @BugFinder did you find a fix for your command? It does not work inside the above code too.

Comment: did you try running the one I suggested - as your uniq would actually give a wrong answer on my machine

Comment: It also has the exactly same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Put an `@` before your argument string to make it a verbatim string. Your string now has the backslash as escape sequence.

```
var proc = new Process
{
   StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
   {
      FileName = "/bin/sh",
      Arguments = @"-c $'grep \""$0\"" /proc/cpuinfo | uniq | sed -e \""$1\"" \""cpu cores\"" 's/[^0-9]*//g''",
      UseShellExecute = false,
      RedirectStandardOutput = true,
      CreateNoWindow = true
   }
};
```

Comment: I tried that earlier as well and tried running your code as well but it still gives the same error i.e. "$0": 1: "$0": Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Comment: @HaseebJadoon I Updated my answer. Maybe its the missing single quote at the end of the regex 's/[^0-9]*//g''

Comment: No still doesn't work. We need to address the argument in some way.

Comment: Impressive mine does the same without parameters .... or the sh command and everything